# Redirect after login in drupal 8

Tags: redirect, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I'm trying to redirect users after login to the destination set in the url, like : /user/login?destination=my-modules

I'm using this module to redirect to login page instead of showing a 403 page : https://www.drupal.org/project/r4032login

It works well and generates the URL with the '?destination=' parameter but after i login i'm redirected to homepage everytime.

The module is supposed to manage this by itself, but i still tried to create a custom module to do the redirection, i created a custom module and installed it, but nothing happens still.

Here is my code :

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
* Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
*/
function test_redirect_form_user_login_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
$form['#submit'][] = 'test_redirect_user_login_form_submit';
}

/**
* Custom submit handler for the login form.
*/
function test_redirect_user_login_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
$url = Url::fromRoute('a route');
$form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
}
```

How do i properly do this ? Thank you

Comment: Make sure that you enabled your module and its machine name is `test_redirect`. I tried your above code and it works perfectly

Comment: I had to change it to $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][]  to make it call the handler, but now i can't get the "destination" parameter in this code.

Comment: Try this: `$request = \Drupal::service('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest(); $destination = $request->request->get('destination');`

Answer (score -1):

I know you asked for help with your code. I'm not super good at custom modules.
Maybe this module will help you:

https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination

I've used it and it's pretty good but may not fit your needs.

Once you install it, you will have the option to set different login destinations for different users found at [mysite.com]/admin/config/people/login-destination

Answer (score -1):

[User Redirect (Redirect user after Login or Logout)](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_redirect) helps to redirect the user after login or logout activity. This module is compatible to the Drupal latest versions and has full security coverage.